# Why mkdir with ssh doesn't want create longname dir?

Tags: ssh, mkdir

Two slackware 14.2 systems,ssh is 7.9p1.

On local system

```
mkdir -p -v "I want to create long dir name with spaces"
mkdir: directory 'I want to create long dir name with spaces' created
```

And is OK

On remote

```
ssh remote mkdir -p -v "I want to create long dir name with spaces"
mkdir: created directory 'I'
mkdir: created directory 'want'
mkdir: created directory 'to'
mkdir: created directory 'create'
mkdir: created directory 'long'
mkdir: created directory 'dir'
mkdir: created directory 'name'
mkdir: created directory 'with'
mkdir: created directory 'spaces'
```

Why?

I have tried using ' instead of " and

```
ssh remote mkdir -p -v 'I want to create long dir name with spaces'
```

Exit with 0(success) but no dir created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

```
ssh remote mkdir -p -v 'I\ want\ to\ create\ long\ dirname\ with\ spaces'
```

I don't understand why on remote is different and I have to escape with `\`.